# Issue when evaluate contour integral :$\frac{b^{z-1}}{1-b}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

So, Im evaluating the contour integral $\frac{b^{z-1}}{1-b}$ along the ccw contour encircling the negative half of the real axis. It seems to be analytic in the whole domain, except for at $ b = 0$ and I'm getting a residue of 0 there. I know that the integral is non-zero, though, and i'm wondering where I went wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you are integrating wrt $b$. Because of the $b^{z-1}$ factor, the integrand on the portion of contour above the negative real axis differs from that below the negative real axis by a factor $e^{2\pi(z-1)i}$. When $z$ is not an integer, the contribution from these two portions of contour didn't cancel out.

Comment: @achillehui I can get that far, but I'm still unable to get that into a usable answer. Do you have any more advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $0 < \Re z <1$, so that your integral converges.

Let $b = -t$, $u = \frac{t}{1+t}$ and notice

$$1 - u = \frac{1}{1+t},\quad t = \frac{u}{1-u}\quad\text{ and }\quad dt = \frac{du}{(1-u)^2}$$

Your integral can be directly evaluated as

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{(0+)} \frac{b^{z-1}}{1-b}db 
= & \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left(
\int_{-\infty-i\epsilon}^{-i\epsilon} + \int_{i\epsilon}^{-\infty+i\epsilon} \right)\frac{b^{z-1}}{1-b} db \\
= & \int_{\infty}^{0} \frac{ e^{-\pi(z-1)i} t^{z-1}}{1+t} d(-t)
+ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ e^{\pi(z-1)i} t^{z-1}}{1+t} d(-t)\\
= & (e^{\pi z i} - e^{-\pi z i})\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{z-1}}{1+t}dt\\
= & 2i\sin(\pi z) \int_0^1 \left(\frac{u}{1-u}\right)^{z-1} (1-u) \frac{du}{(1-u)^2}\\
= & 2i\sin(\pi z) \int_0^1 u^{z-1}(1-u)^{-z} du\\
= & 2i\sin(\pi z) \frac{\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)}{\Gamma(1)}\\
= & 2i\sin(\pi z) \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}\\
= & 2\pi i
\end{align}$$

Alternatively, when $0 < \Re z < 1$, $|b^{z-1}| \to 0$ as $|b| \to \infty$. You can
complete your contour by a clockwise circular loop at $\infty$ and the integral will
remain the same. You then deform your new contour to a circle loop around $1$ in clockwise
direction. Your integral then becomes

$$\int_{(1-)} \frac{b^{z-1}}{1-b} db = -2\pi i\,\text{Res}\left(\frac{b^{z-1}}{1-b};1\right) = -2\pi i (-1) = 2\pi i$$
Same answer as above.